# How to create a realistic shader for french fries?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

I'd like to create a realistic burger and I don't get how to create a shader for my french fries:

[image]

I tried adding procedural textures and displacements, subsurface scattering but unfortunately the shading doesn't look like realistic fries and too flat. Since I'm running out of ideas: What can I do to improve the shader to achieve a plausible and more realistic result?

[image]

Attached a blend with some fries and proper UV's:

[image]

Comment: Please take your time when asking a question. You should know by now, that your question shows no effort, no research and also has some spelling issues. You could at least share a file with the fries using blend-exchange. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method I'd prefer for realism is microdisplacement.  Set your Cycles feature set to experimental so that you can use the *Adaptive* feature of the *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

[image]

[image]

And then set up your material for displacement and bump so that when you connect something to the displacement socket it modifies the mesh.

[image]

I used the same *Noise Texture* for both the *Base Color* and *Displacement*, so that I could make the areas with the most displacement a more golden brown.  The *Scale* values have to be adjusted for the scale you're working at.

[image]

I found that a *Midlevel* of 0 did some work to kind of puff up the model as though it had actually been deep fried, which was kind of fun.

*Subsurface Radius* value was 1, 1, 1 for this shot.

If that doesn't suit, or if a bunch of highly subdivided shapes are going to be too heavy for the final scene, I think it looks ok with *Bump Only*, you'd just have to do some work with the model to avoid it looking flat.  It looks like you have some pretty good shape variations to work with so maybe that's a place to start.

Comment: Something very strange is happening. I have used adaptive subdivision before but any object with another modifier along with the subdivision surface modifier in my scene does not have the adabtive option in the subsurface modifier. I tried both in 2.92 and 2.93 alpha. Why can't I have adaptive subdivision along with other modifiers?

Comment: What I did was I made an archive for the fries and then applied the modifiers other than the subdiv. Now I'll try the microdisplacements.

Comment: Thanks! It looks much better now

Comment: If you drag the subdiv down to the bottom of the modifier stack you can use adaptive