What's the easiest way to make a tater tot/hashbrown texture/bumps in blender?
I'm trying to make a tater tot but have no idea how to start. I've got a cube with a subdivision surface modifier on it, but don't know where to go from here. I'm assuming there must be a way to simulate the edges of a tater tot/hash brown texture but I don't know how I would do that.

Tater tots look like this:


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214004/how-to-create-a-realistic-shader-for-french-fries  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84745/create-irregularly-shaped-gaps-in-cube

Sounds good, thanks!

If you're going to model/ sculpt the bumps of the tater tots, that will not only be tedious, but is on top of that time consuming, as well as much more demanding in computing and rendering time.
I'd suggest you make the rest just with shaders.
I got something like this from that method:

It is completely procedural, is quickly set up and everything about it (coloring, softness, Displacement/Bump) can be changed without any effort.
But first you have to make sure your render engine is set to cycles, as well as to "experimental" instead of "supported". Further more, you have to add another subdivision surface modifier to the cube and tick the little box next to Adaptive Subdivision.
Here's the node tree and last but not least, make sure to change the Displacement Method (Material > Settings > Surface) to Displacement and Bump, just like in the blue marked area in the picture.
After that everything should work just fine:

Alter the settings of the Nodes to adjust the appearence. If you want to, you could switch the Subsurface Scattering Node for a Principled BSDF one.
Hope it helps

Great now I'm hungry! Didn't know you could make tater tots in a Blender

Tell me about something you can't make in blender :)

@NiklasFriedrichs Gravity that affects light paths. Cycles doesn't simulate that :( Although you can make it look like it's doing something for, say, black holes, with a refraction BSDF.

Well...what shall I say about this xD. Your right...maybe i should've limited it to objects
